# How a woman can perform her taraweeh at home?

Tags: ramadan, taraweeh

How a woman can perform her taraweeh at home?

What is the procedure? I mean, I know that she can recite the surahs she has remembered but is it necessary to follow a specific pattern of surah or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that in acts of worship -with a general order or prohibition- any thing which applies to men also do so for women, as we are equal.

Here's a summary of [this fatwa](https://islamqa.info/en/222751):

- You can read/recite what ever you memorize from the Quran.
- You can read/recite from the Mushaf (printed Quran) if  you'd like.
- You shouldn't harm your self in standing, so you don't need to prolong or make the prayer lengthy if you can't endure it.
- For the prayer itself you should perform it two rak'a by two rak'a
- You can pray this way (in the sum) 8 rak'a than shaf'a two rak'a followed by a single rak'a of witr which will make it 11 rak'a in the sum or you may end with a sum of 13 rak'a.

---

Note that 8 is the amount on which all scholars are in consensus, but some have allowed or chosen 20, some have quoted 36 and according to Imam at-Thirmdihi the highest number of rak'a quoted was 41.

For example AFAIK and seen in practice Hanafi's pray the tarawih 20 rak'a divided to 4 by 4 rak'a and end up with a 3 rak'a witr.

---

This is based on the sahih hadith (See for example in Sahih [al-Bukahri](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/14/1), [Muslim](http://sunnah.com/muslim/6/177), [al-Muwatta'](http://sunnah.com/malik/7/13), Sunan [abi Dawod](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/5/77) and [an-Nasa-i](http://sunnah.com/nasai/20/97))

> Prayer during the night should consist of pairs of rak'ahs, but if one
> of you fears morning is near, he should pray one rak'ah which will
> make his prayer an odd number for him.

Note that according [this fatwa](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/139474) (in Arabic) you shouldn't follow an Imam neither if you hear it by radio or TV or because the mosque is very close nor you see him on TV.

You could also these fatawa in Arabic: on [how to](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/112700) pray it, is [praying it in more than 11](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/54790) rak'a bid'ah, [on what basis we pray it](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/11872) as we do, what scholars say about [how much one should read/recite](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/56413)  during a rak'a, see also [this fatwa](https://islamqa.info/en/66504) in English.

And in English: [How many rak'a](https://islamqa.info/en/9036) is taraweh, and [this one again](https://islamqa.info/en/38021) on the amount of rak'a and whether this prayer is bida'ah.

For more information, feel free to ask or check our site by searching via the [taraweeh](/questions/tagged/taraweeh)-tag

Comment: I knew that it applies for both men and women i just unconsciously used the term women's taraweeh sorry for that and thanks for all you explanation it helped me alot.

Comment: Oh thanks for that as well and one more thing the above mentioned links are in Arabic where can i read these fatwa's in English ?

Comment: Okay thanks sir i'll wait and thanks for the guides as well . Stay Blessed. Assalamoalaikum .

Comment: This link just solved all of the confusions . Thanks.