# Is it permissible to skip taraweeh?

Tags: salat, ramadan, prayer-timings, taraweeh

As Muslims, we have to pray fajr, dhuhr, asr, maghrib, and isha. But during Ramadan there is taraweeh prayer. If I skip taraweeh throughout the whole ramadan, is that permissible? Is it ok to skip taraweeh? I heard that taraweeh is optional. (I am a woman.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taraweeh is a night prayer (qiyam al-Lail) that is performed after 'Isha' during Ramadan. It is called taraweeh as it refers to tarweehah a (small) pause between sets of raka'at, this is the origin of the name and early Muslims kneew it as a night prayer so its is basically a night prayer with a different label.
It is not a mandatory prayer, but highly recommended nafl or sunnah.
One can pray it in congregation in a mosque or at home or alone, as it is an optional prayer and the prophet () recommended to pray optional prayers at home in private.
Nevertheless some madhhabs consider praying it in congregation or at home better.
Be aware that basically in Islam women do not need to perform optional prayers and acts of worship, as they might need the permission of their husbands/guardians to do it. I need to add -to avoid misunderstandings- that generally this permission is rather given by mutual agreement and not a big matter as it may sound, but it means if the husband or guardian has any needs he has the right to ask his wife (protegee) to do it instead of for example praying nafl.

Imam Ahmad and ibn Hebban compiled the following hadith:

> from ‘Abd ar-Rahmaan ibn ‘Awf (may Allah bepleased with him) who said: The Messenger of Allah (blessings and peace ofAllah be upon him) said: “If a woman offers her five (daily) prayers, fastsher month (Ramadan), guards her chastity and obeys her husband, it will besaid to her: Enter Paradise by whichever of its gates you wish.” (Source of the translation islamqa #[175885](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/175885/is-it-proven-that-the-righteous-wife-will-have-a-reward-like-that-of-one-who-fasts-and-prays-qiyaam)

Another night prayer that has a special name (as it seems to me only in Ramadan) is tahajjud which is a night prayer which is performed before fajr after taking a nap.

All (with some specifications) the prayers except the five daily prayers are optional prayers and fall under the category nafilah (nafl prayer) some have a higher degree of recommendation and maybe called sunnah or sunnah mu'akkadah or raghibah or even wajib (by hanafis), but this sepecific term only tells us that it is highly recommended to perform this prayer, basically if you pray beside the 5 daily prayers the two rak'a of fajr (nafl/Sunna) and at least (a sum of) 3 raka'at witr you've prayed the most recommended ones. And you might have accomplished the absolut minimum of necessary prayers a day. Therefore you may skip taraweeh, but you must be aware that performing it would be better. You don't need to recite for long nor to make more than 4 sets of two raka'as to accomplish this nafl/sunnah.

See also:

- [How a woman can perform her taraweeh at home?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/32767/how-a-woman-can-perform-her-taraweeh-at-home)
- [Is it obligatory to pray Taraweeh in the mosque?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/32602/is-it-obligatory-to-pray-taraweeh-in-the-mosque)
- [Is taraweeh for women considered as sunnat or nafil?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25516/is-taraweeh-for-women-considered-as-sunnat-or-nafil)